# Having trouble when pragmatically dialing for USSD(like , *222#) code from android version 23 and above

Tags: java, android

I am having some difficulties, when i dialing for `ussd` code in android version 23 and above , code is working fine and ussd is also working correctly. but when i am canceling the ussd dialog box, then doesn't cancel the ussd window, it works continuously in foreground in device. device looks like kind of freeze and have to restart the device for canceling this ussd window. But from android version <23(lollipop to less) everything is working completely fine. How to resolve this problem ?

```
 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23) {
                    if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE)
                            == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                        String phnum = "*247"+Uri.encode("#");
                        Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:" + phnum));
                       // callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phnum));
                        startActivity(callIntent);
                        sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS));
                    } else {
                        Log.v("TAG","Permission is revoked");
                        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MobileTransactionHelp.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE}, 1);
                    }
                } else { //permission is automatically granted on sdk<23 upon installation
                    String phnum = "*247"+Uri.encode("#");
                    Intent callIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL,Uri.parse("tel:" + phnum));
                   // callIntent.setData(Uri.parse("tel:" + phnum));
                    startActivity(callIntent);
                    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CLOSE_SYSTEM_DIALOGS));
                }
```

[image of error : contentiously running ussd window after canceling the ussd window](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1NEPvcRfhN1EheNFycskLbLK705Ncv5Nq)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
if (Pattern.matches("(\\*[0-9]+[\\*[0-9]+]*#)", edtDialPad
                    .getText().toString())) {
                String token = edtDialPad.getText().toString();



                String ussdCode = "" + token.substring(0, token.length() - 1) + Uri.encode("#");
                startActivity(new Intent("android.intent.action.CALL", Uri.parse("tel:"
                        + ussdCode)));

            }
```

Comment: thank you for your answare , but its not working for me .